# Installing Pygame on Mac OS X using Homebrew

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I'm following [these instructions](http://jalada.co.uk/2011/06/17/installing-pygame-on-os-x-with-a-homebrew-python-2-7-install.html) to install Pygame on my Mac.

However, after I get to step 6 (`python config.py`), I get the following error messages:

```
Using Darwin configuration...
Backup existing "Setup" file [Y/n]:Y
Remove old build directory (force recompile) [Y/n]:n
Hunting dependencies...
Framework SDL not found
Framework SDL_ttf not found
Framework SDL_image not found
Framework SDL_mixer not found
Framework smpeg not found
PNG     : not found
JPEG    : not found
SCRAP   : not found
PORTMIDI: not found
Framework CoreMidi found
```

Does anyone know what might be going on?

My SDL include files are in `/usr/local/include/SDL`.

How do I point Python to the right place?

For some reason, when I post the config.py code, it reformats.
It can be found at http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml in the source section.
I'm using the Unix format.

Comment: Post config.py and I'll take a look at it.